# Android ListView dynamically adding data

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

I have a listView that I want to dynamically add data to.
here's the XML I want to add the data to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
  </TextView>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/alarm_name_text" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:text="" 
   android:layout_below="@+id/rowTextView" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent">
   </TextView>

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
    android:focusable="false">
  </CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to add data to the 2nd TextView with the id alarm_name_text after a user has entered some data in an editText dialogView. I've been told to make a function that adds the data the my ArrayList/adapter but I'm not sure when to call it or how it's being used.. I needs help plz :(. Here's the function.

```
public void addItems(View v)
        {
            rowSavedText.setText(getString());
            planetList.add(new Planet("This one"));
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Please give more info: what is the class of your adapter? What is the container of your data?

Comment: it's not necessary for me to put the class, and I specified that I would be using an ArrayList/adapter?
I need help regarding how to add/delete data from a listView of just textViews. Should be relatively simple but I'm have great difficulty with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to work on the part of the code that renders the individual rows. Take a look at the tutorial at http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx: specifically how it uses `getView`.

Comment: This looks extremely helpful, I'm goona check it out right now thanks! :) But I'm still wondering how to dynamically change a textView that I already have from a users input? This just populates the View based on current data.

Comment: You can always remove an item and insert a new one into your Adapter: that should do what you want. You'll need to invoke the `notifyDataSetChanged` method on the adapter to force it to pick up the change.

Comment: wow thanks, My brain just started working. Got an idea :)
One last question about having to add or remove items from my List. Where should I put the functions to add or remove them? And how are they getting invoked?

Comment: You'll need to make sure the invoking happens on the main Activity thread: so in either a listener callback, using a Handler or using `View.post`. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#handler gives a good overview.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've had this problem for about a week now and it's preventing me from going any further. I'll keep trying :)
One thing that I'm not understanding is why I'm getting an error when I Implement my own getItem() function. I can't declare it of type Object, I have to declare it the type of class I want to be. Unlike in the first link you posted for me, http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just add the element to your `ArrayList` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to your array adapter.